# Mi Script PHP Manda correo incompleto con los datos de un WHILE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while, php7

Saludos chicos tengo un conflicto que lo explico a continuacion:

Poseo el siguiente script

```
<?php $sql2 = "SELECT tarjetas.*, users.nombre, users.email, users.username FROM tarjetas INNER JOIN users  ON tarjetas.usuario=users.idusuario WHERE usuario = '$user' AND id_pedido = '$id_pedido' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
//if (mysqli_query($db, $query)){
$row2count =  mysqli_num_rows($result2);
$row2 =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

  $tarjetas = '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">';
  $tarjetas .= '<thead><tr>';
  $tarjetas .= '<th height="17" width ="20%" align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= 'MONTO';
  $tarjetas .= '</th>';
  $tarjetas .= '<th height="17" width ="20%" align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= 'CODIGO';
  $tarjetas .= '</th>';
  $tarjetas .= '<th height="17" width ="20%" align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= 'SERIAL';
  $tarjetas .= '</th>';
  $tarjetas .= '</tr></thead>';

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
  $monto = $row2['monto'];
  $codigo = $row2['codigo'];
  $serial = $row2['serial'];
  $email_usuario = $row2['email'];
  $nombre_usuario = $row2['nombre'];

  $tarjetas .= '<tr>';

  $tarjetas .= '<td align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= $monto;
  $tarjetas .= '</td>';
  $tarjetas .= '<td align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= $codigo;
  $tarjetas .= '</td>';
  $tarjetas .= '<td align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= $serial;
  $tarjetas .= '</td>';
  $tarjetas .= '</tr>';
}
  $tarjetas .=  '</table>';

  $tarjetas_asignadas = $tarjetas;


$email = $email_usuario;
$nombre = $nombre_usuario;
$asunto = "ASUNTO";
$cuerpo = "Hola $nombre <br><br> <h1>FAVOR LEER</h1>
MENSAJE ";
$cuerpo .= '<a href= "#"><b>VER PEDIDO COMPLETO AQUI</b></a>.<br>';
$cuerpo .= "MENSAJE";
$cuerpo .= "<h2>Producto Asignado</h2>";
$cuerpo .= $tarjetas_asignadas;

enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo);
```

El error que presenta es que al enviar un correo lo hace de manera incompleta, me he fijado que el primer dato no lo envia ejemplo del siguiente bloque de datos:

```
monto  codigo   serial
10     111111   1111111
10     222222   2222222
10     333333   3333333
```

Solo llegan al correo

```
monto  codigo   serial
10     222222   2222222
10     333333   3333333
```

El primer dato de la tabla no es enviado y no logro atinar en donde puede estar el error en mi script.

Comment: Elimina esta linea: `$row2 =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);`

Comment: Arriba del todo tú colocas el puntero de datos en la 1ª fila cuando haces esto: `$row2 =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);` y luego, más para abajo lo mueves a la 2ª fila cuando haces: `while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {`  quita el código de arriba y te debería mostrar todas las filas.

Comment: Gracias, simplemente perfecto.